# What processor is better?

Tags: hardware-rec

Processador Intel Xeon E3-1240 (LGA1155 - 3,3GHz) - BX80623E31240SR00K - Box

or

Processador Intel Core i5-2500K (LGA1155 - 3,3GHz) - BX80623I52500KSR008 - Box

I am not very familiar with Xeon procs nor iX classes but from what I readed from both, they are both quad core with 3,3GHz the main differences are L3 cache 1 is 6mb other is 8mb and the TDP being one 80W and the other 95W and the fact the iX have the intel graphs integrated.

Price difference from 1 to another is 50USD where I live.

If it helps the motherboard I was thinking of buying for this is a Gigabyte GA-Z68XP-UD4

Would like to hear some advices from experienced users.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend if your definition of "better" is having 50 USD, or having a tiny bit more performance ?

Comment: Shopping recommendations like this are off-topic, per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on some facts:

If you uses vm's you should get the i5 without k or the xeon, because the k variant does not support Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d).

You also should know the xeon supports ecc memory which is saver but also expensive and your board has to support this feature.

If you want to overclock your system you should buy the i5 k because the its unlocked.

The larger cache will boost the cpu more than 200mhz or 300mhz would do.

If you want detailed informations you should specify your default pc usage behavior.